# How to number code listings in asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm writing a blog in ascidoc and would like the code listings to be automatically numbered, e.g.

```
Listing 1.3 The Hello World code
...
Listing 1.4 Some other code sample
```

Is there an attribute that I can set for the entire text so asciidoc would automatically number code listings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that clear in the [asciidoctor user-manual (Listing Blocks)](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#listing-blocks), but in order for asciidoctor to number the listing you need to:

- add a caption to each block
- set the `listing-caption` attribute at the begining of your document

Example:

```
:listing-caption: Listing

.The Hello World code
----
//TODO: add hello world code
----

.Some other code sample
----
//TODO: Some other code sample
----
```

Controlling the way the listing blocks are numbered (1.1, 1.2 in your example) is not that easy. There is a discussion on GitHub for that.